Bazel dependency analysis
I think a build error is being caused by dependency conflict. I've found the older version of a library using bazel query. These 2.14.0 versions of jackson are conflicting with new versions. I'll try to exclude these from the build so it uses the new versions, but I can not figure out where these came from. My build target does not directly depend on this version and the query output doesn't appear to be structured in a way that I can trace what pulled this in. I tried using rdeps but there doesn't seem to be any version of these that work - just syntax errors. Is there any way I can trace where this came from?
bazel query 'deps(//:target)' --nohost_deps --noimplicit_deps


@maven//:v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.14.0/jackson-annotations-2.14.0-sources.jar
@maven//:v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.14.0/jackson-annotations-2.14.0.jar
@maven//:v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.14.0/jackson-core-2.14.0-sources.jar
@maven//:v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.14.0/jackson-core-2.14.0.jar
@maven//:v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.14.0/jackson-databind-2.14.0-sources.jar
@maven//:v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.14.0/jackson-databind-2.14.0.jar


what errors were you getting with rdeps()? these are the docs: https://bazel.build/query/language#rdeps

You can use somepath() and allpaths() for this: https://bazel.build/query/guide#why-dependencies
bazel query --nohost_deps --noimplicit_deps 'somepath(//:target, @maven//:v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.14.0/jackson-core-2.14.0.jar)'

It's helpful to use --output=graph with allpaths() to get a dot graph to visualize the dependencies (if the graph is small enough)
bazel query --nohost_deps --noimplicit_deps 'allpaths(//:target, @maven//:v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.14.0/jackson-core-2.14.0.jar)' --output=graph | dot -Tpng > /tmp/graph.png

